# I transferred BTC from my blockchain wallet to my trading wallet using my can to address and it never showed up!

Tags: blockchain-wallet-app

Help please! I tried to transfer money from my blockchain wallet to my trading wallet. I even scanned in the QR code so it wouldn't be wrong. My funds never showed up! The wallet it went to seems to have been created the day I did the transfer and since has had many transactions! What the heck happened! I am so confused. How could this have happed with scanning the QR code? It is almost as if the wallet address I sent it to is a receiving account for transfers? Is there such a thing? The other strange thing is I got no emails of any transfers? I have tried to trace the transactions but I don't really understand what I am doing and what it means. Someone said if I have the HASH then I can go in and possibly cancel it if it is unconfirmed. It shows spent now... this was on the 17th and I have sent many emails to blockchain with no response. Should I put the PKscript up or subscript? I can put the receiving wallet up here but I don't think that will do much good unless someone knows a way to find out who it is from that even though it should be MINE! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What trading site did you send it to? The way you describe it it would seem like a scam honestly.

Comment: It was blockchain.com I am beginning to think it was blockchain themselves or an employee! My captcha was glitching or so I thought! I entered correctly 3 times it would just reset and ask again and again so I sent an email @ 2:49pm on 1/17/2021 to blockchain customer service. I go back into my wallet the following day and at 2:50pm 1/17/2021 my money was transferred to someone else’s wallet! I have been taking so many classes online to understand this! It is so confusing!

Comment: Ok, from that it sounds like your login attempt got forwarded to a phishing site when you experienced the captcha problem. If you manually typed the address, or clicked a link (instead of using a saved bookmark), it's highly likely that you ended up on a "fake" blockchain.com site with a very similar address, created to steal usernames and passwords from anyone unlucky enough to end up there. :-(

Comment: Darn it! I am usually good at Ewing those. I do have a question as I done undo this hacking crap. The hackers can they see everything on my computer once they get in or just that website. For phishing it is a fake website which I get but I was able to create a ticket from the website but obviously I can’t tell now... how would I get on a phishing site? Only through email? Or text? Sorry for all the questions, just trying to understand. I am pretty freaked out because I now realize they could do the same thing with my bank account!! They could just wire money & it is gone just like this!

Answer (score 1):

If you transferred funds to the receiving address for your trading account, and the transaction is included/confirmed in a block on the blockchain, but not showing up in your trading account, then you need to contact your trading platform.

A few points to remember here:

1: Once a transaction has been included in a block, it CANNOT be cancelled, voided, or "called back." The only way you could get that bitcoin back is if you have the recipient send it back to you in a new transaction.

2: While most reputable exchanges use separate wallets for each client to deposit to & have servers monitoring for incoming transfers, there is always the possibility of a "glitch" or "server goof." As soon as any deposit to your exchange wallet has more that 3 confirmations on the blockchain, if the exchange hasn't updated your transaction, CONTACT THEM, it could be an honest mistake & if so, they'll be more than happy to correct it for you.

3: All responsibility for making sure your bitcoin transactions go to the right place rests on YOU. Since bitcoin is a decentralized platform, there's no central bank/government you can contact if you make a mistake. Therefore, you should always verify ALL of the information (destination address...read at least the first & last 5 digits, coin amount, and coin type [make sure you don't send BTC to a BCH or BSV wallet]) at least twice BEFORE you confirm sending a transaction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Here is the issue... Now that I have done more research I was locked out of my wallet when the transfer occurred. I have no idea who’s address the transaction went to. What is odd though is that I transferred my bit coin in 2 transactions. 1/2/2021 I transferred 0.00933272 BTC from my coinbase account and then I did a second transaction on 1/14/2021 0.01063528 BTC from the same coinbase wallet. Then on 1/17/2021 who ever took my money did it in the same order. Is that strange? Or am I just thinking it is odd?

Comment: That does sound odd, but in order to make much sense of it I would have to see a lot more data on the wallets in question. ... from what you say, however, it seems highly likely that your account was hacked, and the hacker may have been forced to duplicated previous transaction patterns as part of a security glitch that they were exploiting.

Comment: Robherc KV5ROB Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it. How can a wallet be hacked? I thought it was almost impossible? Although I did hear someone say that Blockchain has holes in their platform and isn’t that secure. Have you experienced such a thing? I confirmed the transfers on the block and it looks like an exchange of some sort but I can not tell. How would a wallet get hacked where they would have visibility to my transactions? I am learning & trying to understand before I do anything else with crypto.I was so scared I went to my bank and told them to block online access

Comment: It's not necessarily your wallet that got hacked, so much as your blockchain account, I'm guessing. Hacking a wallet is only as difficult as hacking the computer where the private key is stored, HOWEVER, many exchanges and "web wallets" use their own wallets to hold the funds, and their system just keeps track of which user's account those funds belong to. On such a platform, anyone who hacked your exchange/web wallet account wouldn't need your private keys, just access to tell the server that your account asked for the transfer.

Comment: That's why it is highly recommended to generate wallets for any "high value" cryptocurrency storage using a hardware wallet device, or on a computer that you never connect to the internet. That way you can use the less secure exchanges & web wallets with funds that won't hurt you as badly if they're lost, but transfer to the "cold storage" wallets for long-term safekeeping.